# Permission required to allow User to Publish/Sync WorkItems from TFS to Project Server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, project-server

I have Team Foundation Server 2010 integrated with Project Server 2010, i want to know what is the permissions required to allow Certain users to Publish/DataSync Work-items from Team foundation Server to Project Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Assign Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg412642%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#assign) section of the "[Administering the Integration of Team Foundation Server and Project Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg412641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)" on MSDN, steps 6-7:

> *Step 6*
>   Add to the Team Members group of PWA.
>   Team Foundation team members who will submit status updates to Project Server from a client of Team Foundation.
>   You must add team members to the Team Members group for the PWA, or you must grant them the following minimum set of Project permissions: Open Project and View Project Site.
>
> *Step 7*
>   Grant permissions to contribute to the team project in Team Foundation Server.
>   Users of Project Professional who will publish plans to Team Foundation.
>   Grant **View Project-level information** permissions in Team Foundation, or assign them as members of the **Reader** group for the team project.